# Single max-width query for mobile and tab devices

Tags: css

is it possible to write a single max-width query which can be compatible for all the mobile and tab devices? Since I am new to css, a help would be appreciated.

Comment: Basically NO....it isn't. There are far too many devices and screen resolutions (with new ones coming all the time) for a SINGLE media query to fit them all.

Comment: You add media queries not for specific devices but rather for when your design *requires* it...it's that simple.

Comment: You should pay attention to the actual break-points of your site, rather than looking for the be-all-end-all of solutions for mobile media queries...

Comment: See when on localhost when I resize the screen to mobile screen by F12, say for eg. I wrote query for 320px,480px,767px,979px and 1200px. I set the width of screen is 360*640, then it is not taking the query of 480px which it should! What is the way out of this?

Answer (score -1):

`@media screen and (max-width: 768px)`

You will also need `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`